# Putty Key Generator Command Line interface?

Tags: command-line, putty, openssh

Is it possible to use Putty Key Generator via command line interface?
I cannot find any documentation.

Any pointers?

Btw, I only want to generate a openssh formatted key pair on a windows machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably out of luck: puttygen (for good reason) doesn't really have a solid command line interface.

For what you need `ssh-keygen` on Windows is probably what you'll need. It takes a bit of work but you might be able to extract it from the mSysGit install at http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list and use that.

Comment: ssh-key works great, files needed, located in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin", are:
- ssh-keygen.exe
- msys-1.0.dll
- msys-crypto-0.9.8.dll
- msys-minires.dll

Comment: @femi What’s the “good reason” here, Femi?

Answer (score 5):

Reading the [source code](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) it appears that there is a command line interface

in the main

```
if (argc > 0) {
if (!strcmp(argv[0], "-pgpfp")) {
    pgp_fingerprints();
    exit(1);
} else {
    /*
     * Assume the first argument to be a private key file, and
     * attempt to load it.
     */
    cmdline_keyfile = argv[0];
}
}
```

you have a choice

- -pgpfp

Which outputs a message:

```
void pgp_fingerprints(void)
{
    fputs("These are the fingerprints of the PuTTY PGP Master Keys. They can\n"
      "be used to establish a trust path from this executable to another\n"
      "one. See the manual for more information.\n"
      "(Note: these fingerprints have nothing to do with SSH!)\n"
      "\n"
      "PuTTY Master Key (RSA), 1024-bit:\n"
      "  " PGP_RSA_MASTER_KEY_FP "\n"
      "PuTTY Master Key (DSA), 1024-bit:\n"
      "  " PGP_DSA_MASTER_KEY_FP "\n", stdout);
}
```

- a keyfilename which is later used to

  if (cmdline_keyfile)
   load_key_file(hwnd, state, filename_from_str(cmdline_keyfile), 0);
  return 1;`

My suggestion is follow the code and see what's what.

Comment: You're looking at the source code of putty, which isn't used to generate keys.  You need to look at puttygen. -pgpfp displays the PGP key fingerprints.

Comment: I downloaded the entire source - it includes putty gen.

Answer (score 4):

You could try and use the [unix version](http://linux.die.net/man/1/puttygen) of puttygen via cygwin.

There is also a writeup as to [why puttygen doesn't support command line in Windows](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/puttygen-batch.html). With the window version you can only specify the keyfile for it to load initially.